# Azure B2C custom policy how to test an error page custom screen

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

In our B2C environment, we are testing using custom screens to change the user interface of each screen in our custom policies.

So far I have been able to update these and test them. However when it comes to the error page:

```
<ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
  <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/exception.cshtml</LoadUri>
  <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
  <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
  <Metadata>
    <Item Key="DisplayName">Error page</Item>
  </Metadata>
</ContentDefinition>
```

I have updated the LoadUri line to point to our custom screen:

```
<LoadUri>https://xxxxx.blob.core.windows.net/xxxxx/custom-error.html</LoadUri>
```

However, how can I go about testing what this displays? For the other screens it is possible as you step through each policy. But the error screen should only show when a relevant error occurs. How can I initiate an error to do this?

Comment: I'm reaching within the product team and will come back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test the Error page by going to the Authorization endpoint without passing a client Id. For example:

https://mytenant.b2clogin.com/mytenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_signup_signin/oauth2/authorize