# How to customize error text in Azure B2C error page api.error

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

Consider the error page from Azure B2C

[image: Azure B2C global exception]

**Question 1**: How can we customize the text in this image?

**Question** 2: Should we expect only this text and html structure (h2 and some divs) to appear or may it change depending on the internal/server error?

**Question 3**: The custom policy is validated only if we add         `<RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>`, but this url seems inexistant and we do not know what it is meant to display??

We are using custom policies with a `ContentDefinition` `DataUri`

```
 <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
```

Went through: [Azure B2C custom policy how to test an error page custom screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64352251/azure-b2c-custom-policy-how-to-test-an-error-page-custom-screen)

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids), there does not appear to be a built-in way of customizing or localizing the text on the error page. I tried creating a LocalizedString of the UxElement type with a StringId of error-help (That appears to be the content ID of the body text if you examine the page source) but it didn't seem to do anything. Even when using the ui_locales query param described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/language-customization?pivots=b2c-custom-policy) and setting my browser language, the page is always displayed in English. It looks like the only way to customize the text on the error page is with custom HTML/CSS/JS for now.
2. As far as I can tell, the globalexception data URI (The data contract associated with the api.error content definition) is consistent in its HTML structure. The error-title and error-help text is always the same, but the correlation ID, timestamp, and exception message will differ depending on the circumstances.
3. RecoveryUri doesn't appear to be used according to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#contentdefinition). It's required element of the ContentDefinition block and can only ever have a value of '~/common/default_page_error.html'. Not sure what its future intended purpose is, but perhaps it's meant to serve as a fallback if the LoadUri fails. For now, it just has to be that constant value in all of your content definitions because, uh, reasons.